# Getting a black screen with large X shaped cursor

Tags: 14.04, boot

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I was trying to start mining. Following a YouTube video blindly, I ran a command which was

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

That gave me a black screen with a large X shaped cursor. And now I get stuck there on every reboot.

[image: image of screen]

I have tried adding text to the boot line in order to boot into text mode but I still get the same screen.

How can I fix this issue?